# Bash Using Sed on a Variable

Tags: bash, sed

I have an xml file which will always have the following block inside of it:

```
<Name NameType="Also Known As">
  <NameValue>
    <FirstName>name1</FirstName>
    <Surname>sur1</Surname>
  </NameValue>
  <NameValue>
    <FirstName>name2</FirstName>
    <Surname>sur2</Surname>
  </NameValue>
</Name>
```

There may be just one "NameValue" node inside this block or there may be many. My issue is that I only ever want to keep the first one and discard the rest. The example above would hence read:

```
<Name NameType="Also Known As">
  <NameValue>
    <FirstName>name1</FirstName>
    <Surname>sur1</Surname>
  </NameValue>
</Name>
```

I'd like to use sed for this purpose. I have written the above block to a variable and tried to manipulate that as follows:

```
var=$(sed -n '/<Name NameType="Also Known As">*/,/<\/Name>/p' $file)
sed -i 's/<\/NameValue>.*<\/Name>/<\/NameValue><\/Name>/g' "$var"
```

I get the following in return:

```
sed: can't read <Name NameType="Also Known As">...
```

I thought the above would have replaced everything between the first closing NameValue tag and the closing Name tag with nothing. I used the -i option as I want to save the changes to this file. Perhaps it's syntax related, or maybe my understanding of using the sed command on a variable is way off. A point to note is that these tags occur inside other nodes in the file and so doing one blanket update using sed would change blocks which i don't want to change. This is the reason I passed this block to a variable. Any pointer's in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: sed operates on files and streams (Stream EDitor), not variables. Put your variable contents into one of those.

Comment: Well you can also say `sed '... things ...' <<< "$var"`.

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio. I've taken your advise and outputted the contents of that variable to a file where I can easily enough do the string manipulation that I need. I can then replace that block in the original file with the contents of this new file (or at least that's what i'm currently attempting to do). I'm fully aware that this isn't the cleanest solution, and perhaps with time and more experience using shell commands I'll avoid this type of approach but for now I'm just after something that works. Thanks again for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the previous comments point out, `sed` expects one or several input files (which may be something like stdin, of course). In your example code, you read the **content** of a file into a variable in a roundabout way, and then use that variable as the **name** of a file. That is bound to fail. While I'm sure you could achieve your objectives using `sed`, I do not advise it. Branching in `sed` is horrible. Use a more powerful tool, preferably `xsltproc` or something else that is designed to work with XML.

You could use a stylesheet similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/Name">
    <Name>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="*[1]" />
    </Name>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael. You're right, using sed is messy for this purpose, but as it happens I almost have something together that I think will might work with a few more tweeks. This particular xml doesn't have an associated xsl file (Or at least i was never provided with one... only an xsd), so i'm not sure if xsltproc would be of any use to me. I've never used it before regardless. I'll keep cracking on anyways, and thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as you took the time to provide an example of a style sheet I could use for the problem. In hindsight, my original question should have been "How to create an xsl file from an xml" file. Many thanks.